# How to create overlapping div elements with css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a div element of size 1000x600. Inside it, I want to create several divs of size 50x50. I want to make all the small div bottom left aligned. But they need to overlap and all go on that corner on top of each other in the bigger div. Then I want to control the positioning of the divs such that they are independent of the other small divs, i.e. they can all overlap.

When I try it, the divs just stack on top of each other. If I use position absolute, then the divs are then relative to the whole page and appear outside of the big div, I need it relative to the bigger div.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I remind you that some code would be nice to see. (BTW... I did not understand a word! :) Can you clarify your thoughts?)

Comment: Have you tried giving the bigger div `position: relative`? That should allow you to use absolute positioning on the smaller divs.

Comment: You are saying to align bottom left and again to top corner. Very confusion, and of your last question apply relative position to bigger div.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what you're asking without some sample code or at least a drawing of what you're trying to achieve. But...

"If I use position absolute, then the divs are then relative to the whole page and appear outside of the big div, I need it relative to the bigger div"

You want to set `position: relative` on the parent container (the big div). Then child elements with `position: absolute` will be positioned relative to the big div.

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/LsL4p/

1.) Add **"position:relative"** to conatiner div

2.) Add **"position:absolute;left:0;bottom:0"** to small div.

```
.container{
        border:1px solid #333333;    
        position:relative;
        width:1000px;
        height:600px;
}
.small-div{
        border:1px solid red;   
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
}
```